# how to pass output of a command to another in shell script

Tags: docker, shell, ssh, sh

I am trying to ssh into server, and into a docker container to run the service. however I am not able to store containerId into a variable to pass it to enter the container.

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh test_server << EOF
 ls 
 sudo docker ps | grep 'tests_service_image' | colrm 13                 # This command works
 containerId=$(sudo docker ps | grep 'tests_service_image' | colrm 13)  # This doesn't
 sudo docker exec -i "$containerId" bash                           # Throws error since containerId is empty
 ./run.sh 
EOF

exit
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing variable/function expansions on your own side. You need to escape those so that those expansions happen on the server side.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

ssh test_server << EOF
 containerId=\$(sudo docker ps | grep 'tests_service_image' | colrm 13)
 sudo docker exec -i "\$containerId" bash
 ./run.sh 
EOF

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:
Pass it directly to docker exec command like so

`sudo docker exec -i $(sudo docker ps | grep 'tests_service_image' | colrm 13) bash`

**Original Answer**:

This is written assuming that the script execution is done post sshing into the server. but modified the answer to above based on the specific query

container ID is stored in variable `containerId`, you are getting the error `Error: No such container:` because you are passing a different variable `$container` instead of `$containerId` to docker exec command.

Comment: It's a typo, corrected it. Still doesn't work.

Comment: The error is container not found since containerId is empty when passed into sudo docker exec command

Comment: Do not store it in a seperate variable, pass it directly to docker exec command like so `sudo docker exec -i $(sudo docker ps | grep 'tests_service_image' | colrm 13) bash`

Comment: echo $containerid to ensure you have an actual id in the variable.